# Efficiently counting items in large python lists

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, list

I have two very large python lists that look like this:

```
List A: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4.........]
List B: [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4.........]
```

These lists go on to very large numbers, but I specify a maximum value, say **100** and after that I can discard the rest.

Now I need to calculate for each value (0,1,2..**100**) the ratio: occurrences in list A / occurrences in list B. And since this value is not always possible I decided to calculate this value only if there's more than 5 occurrences of the value in each list, and if this condition is not true, then combine the occurrences of the previous value(s) and will give the same ratios for combined values if this condition is correct. 
For example for the above lists, I want to create a Series that looks like this:

```
0 : 7/6=1.166 
1 : 9/6 = 1.5
2 : 9/6 = 1.5
3 : 9/6 = 1.5
.
.
.
100 : some_number
```

Comment: 7 = count of "0" in list A, 6 = count of "0" in list B.. 7/6 = 1.166

Comment: Why is 1 `1 : 9/6 = 1.5` instead of `1 : 4/0 = ...`?

Comment: Why more than 5? It should just be more than 0

Comment: If you have 2 lists, then I see no way around looking at each element in the list at least once. So 2 list with N elements means you're looking at 2N run time. Just loop through your lists.

Comment: Answering  Nick A: Because as explained, the ratio should only be calculated if there are more than 5 occurrences of the value in each list. 1 appears in list A only 4 times and never in list B, so it should be combined with the next value: 2. Even when these 2 were combined it didn't answer the requirements so the value 3 was also combined, and then occurrences of 1+2+3 are 9 in list A and 6 in list B - so the ratio calculated was 9/6 = 1.5.

Comment: Are the lists sorted? In that case, it might be feasible to use binary search to find every steps.

Comment: The lists are sorted

Comment: @TripleNipple Ah yes, sorry I missed that part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `Counter` to count the occurences and `takewhile` to fill your requirement of stopping at `100`.

Instead of discarding values which are not in list `b`, notice how I used `nan`.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

def get_ratios(a, b, max_=None, min_count=0):
    if max_ is not None:
        a = takewhile(lambda x: x <= max_, a)
        b = takewhile(lambda x: x <= max_, b)

    count_a, count_b = Counter(a), Counter(b)

    return {k: float('nan') if not count_b[k] else count_a[k] / count_b[k]
            for k in set(count_a) | set(count_b)
            if count_a[k] >= min_count <= count_b[k]}
```

### Example

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 101]
b = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 101]

print(get_ratios(a, b, max_=100))
```

### Output

```
{ 1: 1.5,
  2: 0.5,
  3: nan,
  4: 0.0 }
```

To ignore some under represented values, you can set `min_count` to `5` as mentionned in your question.

Notice I didn't fill in empty slots with the ratio of the previous value. Unless you have a very specific use case that requires it, I recommend you do not as this would mix *actual* data with *extrapolated* data. It is better to default on the previous value when it is not found, but to not pollute the actual data.